# Series Convergence proof involving logs

Tags: limits

The questions is to show whether the following is convergent or divergent

$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ ln\ k } }  } $

I can see that convergence will occur (thinking about comparison with $\frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } } $ )

however this comparison is only true for k>2.

Would the following be the best approach?

$$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ lnk } } =\frac { 1 }{ { 1 }^{ ln1 } } +\frac { 1 }{ { 2 }^{ ln2 } } + } \sum _{ k=3 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ lnk } }  } $$

and now using the comparison test on

$\sum _{ k=3 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ lnk } } <\sum _{ k=3 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } }  }  } $

With the final claim regarding the convergence of a convergent series + constant is convergent??

thanks

Comment: this is a correct solution. The convergence of a series depends on the "tail".

Comment: thanks voldemort .. the given solution compared $\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ lnk } } <\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } }  }  } $  which i had issue with.

Comment: to add, the issue I had was with the statement  $\frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ lnk } } <\frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } } $

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $k \geq 8$, $ln(k) > 2$, so, $k^{ln k} > k^2$, and hence $\dfrac{1}{k^{ln k}} \leq \dfrac{1}{k^2}$. The first 7 terms are finite anyway, and so doesn't affect the convergence (or in general divergence) of the series.